# Making CSV used as query for selecting some features?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
selected_features=layer.selectedFeatures()
print layer.name()
l = []
for i in selected_features:
    l.append(i.attribute("ID"))
print(l)
```

When I run this in Python console I got `[10,11,12,14]` now I want to export this text `[10,11,12,14]` in one line of `csv`-file, and use it later for selecting features.

With a result of `print(l)` I want to select features in my `activeLayer()`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, so you want to select features that are already selected?  Can you elaborate more how the layer relates to the csv text?

Comment: Yes when i print(l) i get in python console [10,12,13,14] now i wont to use this text [10,12,13,14] for selecting features whit this ID.

Comment: Is the current active layer you have in the code the cav table?

Comment: Please add these details by editing the question

Comment: from qgis.core import *
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer() 
# Load the layer
#layer = QgsVectorLayer('C:/Users/.../ne_10m_populated_places_simple.shp','Population', 'ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
# Write the filter expression and set it
#query = '"ID" = 10'
text='"ID" = 10 or "ID" = 11 or "ID" = 12'
query = text
selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])

Comment: Your code is just fine except : `print (layer.name())` ...